# Manually get value of pointer | error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c, pointers

I have a address (pointerAddress) and want to get the value of the preceding address.

I thought I could understand it like this:

1. give me the address: (pointerAddress - sizeof(uint32_t))
2. convert it to a pointer type: (void *)
3. give me the value of the pointer: *

But I keep getting this error. But the second approch does work.

```
// doesnt work
return *(void *)(pointerAddress - sizeof(uint32_t));

// works
uint32_t *v = (void *)(pointerAddress - sizeof(uint32_t));
return *v;
```

**EDIT:**

**full example**

```
uint32_t *pointerAddress;
void push(uint32_t v)
{
    *pointerAddress = v;
    pointerAddress = (void *)(pointerAddress+ sizeof(uint32_t));    
}

uint32_t pop()
{
    pointerAddress = (void *)(pointerAddress- sizeof(uint32_t));
    return *pointerAddress;
}
```

lets say: `pointerAddress = malloc(100 * sizeof(uint32_t));`

Comment: You cannot dereference a `void` pointer.

Comment: if I changed the first (void *) to a (uint32_t*) would both the variants be the same or would I have some stack memeory problems?

Comment: In that case both would be the same, you would not have any problems, assuming the rest of the code is correct.

Comment: You have potentially several problems. What is `pointerAddress`? Pointer arithmetic is undefined behaviour except in certain specific situations. And why are you attempting to dereference the result?

Comment: If you provide a MRE of a use case we would be able to provide a more comprehensive assessment.

Comment: i addded a full example. What do you mean with "Pointer arithmetic is undefined behaviour except in certain specific situations."?

Comment: Look at **$6.5.6** (subsection 8) of [this C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: Note that a simple `--pointerAddress` will reduce the address value by the size of a `uint32_t` type. Why all the hassle of casting to/from a `void*`?

Comment: I made a whole lot wrong by adding sizeof(uint32_t) to my pointer. That ended up adding 4 times 32 bits, jeez.